# Free tool to throttle traffic between local IIS (loopback) and browser on local machine?

Tags: windows, iis, networking, network-traffic, bandwidth-throttling

I want to do some performance tests on my dev box and want to throttle/slow down the traffic between the local IIS and the browser. I used the free NetBalanacer tool but it doesn't seem to support local traffic (using loopback adapter).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler can simulate slow speed and latency. http://www.fiddler2.com

In general, Fiddler is a great HTTP debugging tool, that should be in any web developers toolbox :-)

Comment: If you mean to use "Simulate Modem Speeds", I had it turned on but the response was extremely slow. Since it mentions 'Speeds', is there a way to adjust the speed?

Comment: Yes, it can be scripted, see for instance: http://mrentropy.blogspot.dk/2008/12/using-fiddler-to-simulate-dsl-speeds.html (ie.: change the trickle speed)