# How to make a website load *slower* on browser?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension

For some users acceptance test, we need to write a chrome extension that will make specific sites (i.e, www.cnn.com, and so forth) load slower - kind of imitating a slow internet connection. Any idea on how to approach this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free tool to throttle traffic between local IIS (loopback) and browser on local machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358921/free-tool-to-throttle-traffic-between-local-iis-loopback-and-browser-on-local)

Comment: Is *extension* a requirement? A proxy that is run locally and slows down connections to certain sites would be easier, and I guess such tools can already exist.

Comment: @Oded - we need an extension, not a tool

Comment: Um. What you said you need is a way to load sites slower. Why this needs to be an extension is very unclear.

Comment: Oded, we need it as part of a specific eco-system. That's what product wants :)

Answer (score 3):

Does it *have* to be Chrome Extensions? Because there is this thing called [Sloppy](http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/) for example.

Comment: That's great! What we need is Sloppy as an extension :)